# Loop through database contents depending on ID

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have an azure PHP Web App with MySQL database.

I need to access 2 tables in the database and loop through each entry, displaying the content connected to each ID.

Database set up:

Driver

| driverID | driverName |
| --- | --- |
| (AI) 1 | Bob |

openJobs

| jobID | jobName | jobDate | destination | etc etc etc | driver_FK | driverName_FK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (AI) 1 | job 1 | Monday, 1st Sep | New Zealand | blah blah | (get from driver) | (get from Driver) |

Here is my code:
I also have a connection linked elsewhere. And I haven't added the join for the drivers name yet.

```
function openJobsList()
{
    global $conn;
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT openjobs.jobName, openjobs.jobType, openjobs.orderNumber, openjobs.referenceNumber, openjobs.pallets, openjobs.jobWeight, openjobs.jobStatus, driver.DriverID, driver.driverName
                                    FROM openjobs
                                    INNER JOIN driver ON openjobs.driver_fk = driver.DriverID");

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {

        $id = $row['DriverID'];
        //$driverName_fk = $row['driverName_fk'];
        $jobName = $row['jobName'];
        $jobType = $row['jobType'];
        $orderNumber = $row['orderNumber'];
        $referenceNumber = $row['referenceNumber'];
        $pallets = $row['pallets'];
        $jobWeight = $row['jobWeight'];
        $jobStatus = $row['jobStatus'];

        echo "<div class='card mainPageJobCard my-2'>
                <div class='card-body'>
                    <div class='row justify-content-between'>
                        <div class='col-11'>
                            <h5 class='card-title'>Driver: {$id}</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class='col-1'>
                            <a href='pages/webAddJob.php' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm text-light rounded-pill'>Add Job</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='row'>
                        <div class='col pt-3'>
                            <table class='table table-bordered table-responsive'>
                                <thead>
                                 <tr class='table-light'>
                                        <th scope='col' class='col-2'>Job</th>
                                        <th scope='col'>Type</th>
                                        <th scope='col' class='col-2'>Order #</th>
                                        <th scope='col' class='col-2'>Reference</th>
                                        <th scope='col'>Pallets</th>
                                        <th scope='col'>Weight (kg)</th>
                                        <th scope='col' class='col-2'>Status</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                    <tr>
                                       <th>{$jobName}</th>
                                       <td>{$jobType}</td>
                                       <td>{$orderNumber}</td>
                                       <td>{$referenceNumber}</td>
                                       <td>{$pallets}</td>
                                       <td>{$jobWeight}</td>
                                       <td>{$jobStatus}</td>
                                    </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>";
    }
}
```

That successfully gets the DriverID and shows all jobs assigned to it but they show like this:
(See driver 6)

[image: Screenshot of what is showing currently]

But I am needing it to show each job assigned to the ID number together not in different blocks, like this: (ignore the difference in design etc)

[image: Screenshot of what I need it to look like]

I'm assuming I need a second loop to run inside the first one but I am stumped on what I would put as the condition in the second loop.

Comment: **I need a second loop to run inside the first one.**  Hint: (a) query in 1st loop, select the distinct driver id, driver name. (b) query in 2nd loop: select those data related to this driver id.

Comment: Thank you! That seems to have worked as it's added multiple jobs to the drivers but it still repeats the same driver and jobs depending on how many are assigned to the driver. Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

Just create an array using the query result, create a multidimensional array having driver id as array key. And you will have an array like this,

```
Array
(
    [driver_id1] => Array
        (
            [0] => [job1]
            [1] => [job2]
            [2] => [jbo3]
        )

    [driver_id2] => Array
        (
            [0] => [job1]
            [1] => [job2]
            [2] => [jbo3]
        )

)
```

and then loop that created array. It will create a box for the drivers and another loop inside the table body to show related jobs for the driver.

```
function openJobsList()
{
$data = [];
    global $conn;
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT openjobs.jobName, openjobs.jobType, openjobs.orderNumber, openjobs.referenceNumber, openjobs.pallets, openjobs.jobWeight, openjobs.jobStatus, driver.DriverID, driver.driverName
                                    FROM openjobs
                                    INNER JOIN driver ON openjobs.driver_fk = driver.DriverID");

while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
     $data[$id][] = $rows
}

    foreach($rows as $driver => $value ) {

        $id = $driver;


        echo "<div class='card mainPageJobCard my-2'>
                <div class='card-body'>
                    <div class='row justify-content-between'>
                        <div class='col-11'>
                            <h5 class='card-title'>Driver: {$id}</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class='col-1'>
                            <a href='pages/webAddJob.php' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm text-light rounded-pill'>Add Job</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='row'>
                        <div class='col pt-3'>
                            <table class='table table-bordered table-responsive'>
                                <thead>
                                 <tr class='table-light'>
                                        <th scope='col' class='col-2'>Job</th>
                                        <th scope='col'>Type</th>
                                        <th scope='col' class='col-2'>Order #</th>
                                        <th scope='col' class='col-2'>Reference</th>
                                        <th scope='col'>Pallets</th>
                                        <th scope='col'>Weight (kg)</th>
                                        <th scope='col' class='col-2'>Status</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                   <?php foreach($value as $row){
                                         $jobName = $row['jobName'];
                                         $jobType = $row['jobType'];
                                         $orderNumber = $row['orderNumber'];
                                        $referenceNumber = $row['referenceNumber'];
                                        $pallets = $row['pallets'];
                                        $jobWeight = $row['jobWeight'];
                                         $jobStatus = $row['jobStatus'];
                                      }?>
                                    <tr>
                                       <th>{$jobName}</th>
                                       <td>{$jobType}</td>
                                       <td>{$orderNumber}</td>
                                       <td>{$referenceNumber}</td>
                                       <td>{$pallets}</td>
                                       <td>{$jobWeight}</td>
                                       <td>{$jobStatus}</td>
                                    </tr> 
                                    <?php } ?>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't get that to work though unfortunately.